# Event Handlers not being invoked in IE 9

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to add event handlers to the `option` elements contained inside a `select` box. 
The relevant code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.custom_select_option_1').mousedown(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var opt= event.target;
        var scroll_offset= opt.parentElement.scrollTop;
        opt.selected= !opt.selected;
        opt.parentElement.scrollTop= scroll_offset;
        update_selections(opt.parentElement);
    });
    $('.custom_select_option_1').mousemove(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My code works fine in Chrome, but in `IE-9` the default event handlers are invoked instead.

How can I adapt this code so that it works in `IE-9`?

Comment: Can you post the complete code? I don't even get this working in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Internet Explorer does not support the `mousedown` event for option elements.

A list of the events it does support can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To do this in IE, you have to implement your own select box with JS/CSS using some other type of elements besides `<option>` and `<select>`.

I suggest using `<ul>` and `<li>`.